# Manipulating location is failing because of < and > in location

Tags: rascal

I have a location

`|java+class:///smallsql/database/CommandDrop|(114,115,<3,68>,<8,5>)`

which I would like to convert to

`|project://SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/CommandDrop.java|(114,115,<3,68>,<8,5>)`.

I want to do this by using `toString`, then manipulate the resulting `String` and then apply a `toLocation`. However, this is failing because `toString` will turn `<` into `\<` and similar for `>`. Now `toLocation` will see it as a malformed URI. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate a path of a location, keeping the rest the same, just do it like this:

```
myLoc.path = myManipulation(myLoc.path);
```

where `myManipulation` is a function.

But to me it seems you just want to resolve the logical location to a physical one:

```
import IO;
myLoc = resolveLocation(myLoc);
```

Mind you, the project's M3 model must have been registered before using `analysis::m3::Registry::registerProject` otherwise the resolution won't work.

You can also directly look up the path you need by looking it up in the M3 model's `declarations` table.

Comment: I indeed want to convert the logical location to a physical one. That happens with resolveLocation, but without taken into account offsets for comments. I also tried to use something like ``myM3model@declarations[|java+class:///smallsql/database/CommandDrop|(114,115,<3,68>,<8,5>)]`` but that yields an empty set.